# Problem modulating action script project

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, module

I am refactoring a hugh action script solution in Flash builder (beta 2) using the flex 4 sdk.
The project does NOT use the mx framework.

What i want to have is:

- A big 'MAIN' project
- several small 'MODULE' projects. each 'MODULE' class refrences the 'MAIN' project as an External reference (doesnt compile into swf) - this is done by setting link type = external in the 'MODULE' project properties -> library path.
- 'MAIN' loads a 'MODULE' project on runtime using the 'loader' class.

the problem:
I recieve an error from the MODULE project:

**VerifyError: Error #1014: Class [some class in MAIN] could not be found.**

PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 0):

Check which application domain you are loading your module into. The app domain needs to be able to access the class you have externalised or you'll get that error.

Comment: The app domain im using is ApplicationDomain.current - but no luck

Answer (score 0):

It might just be a bug with the beta version of the sdk. It seems like the import of a class in a module created in another project doesn't force it's inclusion in the main swf.

try putting a dummy dependency in you main application class, like:

```
private var forcedImports:Array = [MyClass];
```

It fixed some of my problems before.